# Alter MS Access Report output after its loaded

Tags: ms-access

I am using MS Access 2007. I have a table, where, among other things, I have a hyperlink field. There, I save hyperlinks to images associated with the records. Now, I'd like to have a MS access report where I could output these records, but instead of displaying clickable hyperlink fields, I'd like to show the images themselves.

I know I can add an unbound images to MS Access report, but I cannot figure out how to proceed. I imagine I could have images with "random" source, and on report generation just replace the source with the values from my hyperlink fields. But so far I have found no examples / documentation to anything similar - what events should I use, how can I iterate through the records that are being printed out?

**Edit:**

Thanks to @HK1, I found the Detail_Format event. However, it is only triggered when PrintPreview view is loaded, not the Report view. That would not be a problem in itself, as I can simply switch back-and-forth between views, but a strange thing happens:

In Print preview, the three records would be updated each based on their respective values. When switching back to ReportView, they suddenly all obtain the value of the last record.

For example, say I have a textbox "foo" and three records with IDs 1,2,3. The code:

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
  Me!foo.Caption = Me!ID.value
End Sub
```

It updates the three textboxes to contain 1, 2 and 3 respectively in the PrintPreview view. After switching back, I get all three textboxes with 3. Any ideas how I could fix that?

Comment: So do you want clickable hyperlink images or just images? You can set the value of a control during the Detail_OnFormat event which occurs as each record gets loaded and formatted on the report.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that Detail_OnFormat fires on each record. Just checked and strangely - the event is not firing (at all). I even tried random example with it (shading alternate rows: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/shading-alternating-rows-in-reports-HA001219146.aspx) and it did not work, either. Anything I might be missing?

Comment: OK, figured something. If I just open Report View. nothing happens. But if I switch to Print View and then Back to Report View, the Format event is triggered. Now. Is there any way to avoid switching views?

Comment: I think you need to go by what you see in PrintPreview and in the actual printout and not worry about what shows in ReportView. What are you using to create the value? If you're using a report level variable that increments on each Format event, you need to remember that the report might "load" more than once just to display a single time so it can mess up incrementing variables by incrementing them twice.

Comment: would be good if people needed printouts in the end - I intended for them to use the Report view in the end :) And, I am not using any variables, it an assignment as simple as given in the example in the post.

Comment: I'm not familiar with doing what you're trying to do on the "ReportView". If you don't get any more help here at StackOverflow, I recommend you ask about this problem over on UtterAccess.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article: [Use images in your Access forms, reports and controls](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/use-images-in-your-access-forms-reports-and-controls-HA001147204.aspx). In it they discuss the pros and cons of a variety of approaches when dealing with images in Access.

Comment: Thanks for the link - while it does list out many ways to store images, I could not really find information that would help my setup.